# I want to Integrate Mpesa API with a django website

Tags: django, mpesa

I am trying to integrate mpesa to a django website where a user completes filling a form then proceeds to pay for the service to be offered using lipa na mpesa before proceeding with the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you stuck at exactly, to enable us give you a working solution? A for that am guessing you probable need to use Mpesa Express.

Answer (score 1):

It is really not clear where you are stuck with your Mpesa integration. However, Mpesa integration on any website is very easy if you use this [Mpesa integration guide](https://www.paymentprocessor-script.com/b2c-mpesa-integration-on-your-website-step-by-step-for-non-programmers.html). It works even for non-programmers. What needs a developer is the business logic to extend the integration point.